# Archlinux: No binaries can be executed

Tags: linux, arch-linux

Yesterday I ran an archlinux system upgrade which updated a lot of things, one of them being glibc.

```
looking for inter-conflicts...

Targets (4): bash-4.2.045-5  glibc-2.18-11  libarchive-3.1.2-4  pacman-4.1.2-4

Total Installed Size:   40.34 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:       -2.55 MiB

Proceed with installation? [Y/n] Y
(4/4) checking package integrity                   [######################] 100%
(4/4) loading package files                        [######################] 100%
(4/4) checking for file conflicts                  [######################] 100%
(4/4) checking availbale disk space                [######################] 100%
(1/4) upgrading glibc                              [######################] 100%
warning: /etc/locale.gen installed as /etc/locale.gen.pacnew
call to execv failed (No such file or directory)
error: command failed to execute correctly
(2/4) upgrading bash                               [######################] 100%
call to execv failed (No such file or directory)
error: command failed to execute correctly
(3/4) upgrading libarchive                         [######################] 100%
(4/4) upgrading pacman                             [######################] 100%
warning: /etc/pacman.conf installed as /etc/pacman.conf.pacnew
[root@renfield3 ~]# pacman -S filesystem --force
-bash: /usr/bin/pacman: No such file or directory
[root@renfield3 ~]# which pacman
-bash: /usr/bin/which: No such file or directory
[root@renfield3 ~]# /usr/bin/pac
paccache           paclist            pacman-key         pacsort
pacdiff            paclog-pkglist     pacman-optimize    pacsysclean
pack200            pacman             pacscripts         pactree
packer             pacman-db-upgrade  pacsearch
[root@renfield3 ~]# /usr/bin/pac
paccache           paclist            pacman-key         pacsort
pacdiff            paclog-pkglist     pacman-optimize    pacsysclean
pack200            pacman             pacscripts         pactree
packer             pacman-db-upgrade  pacsearch
[root@renfield3 ~]# /usr/bin/pacman
-bash: /usr/bin/pacman: No such file or directory
[root@renfield3 ~]# /usr/bin/pacman
-bash: /usr/bin/pacman: No such file or directory
[root@renfield3 ~]# ls /usr/bin
-bash: /usr/bin/ls: No such file or directory
[root@renfield3 ~]# cd
[root@renfield3 ~]# cd .
[root@renfield3 /]# cd ..
[root@renfield3 /]# sudo ls /usr/bin
-bash: /usr/bin/sudo: No such file or directory
[root@renfield3 /]# bash ls /usr/bin
-bash: /usr/bin/bash: No such file or directory
[root@renfield3 /]# chmod
-bash: /usr/bin/chmod: No such file or directory
```

Obviously the upgrade of glibc failed. But as you can see on the bottom I cannot execute anything anymore. The files themselves are still there, which i can see using `echo /usr/bin/*`

Since I cannot run anything on the machine: is there any way to fix this? Or am I forced to re-install the whole OS?

Comment: please try command whereis ls and see what the command returns. ideally you should get the path to the binary. Also check the PATH

Comment: What exactly is the point of typing 'whereis ls' The user already stated that binaries cannot be executed.

Comment: If /bin/sh still works you might be able to fix it, but at this point it will probably be faster to reinstall.

Comment: This is the perfect time for rescue mode.  Most distros provide some kind of rescue environment, where you can boot from RO media and mount your machine's root partition, then using normal package management tools redirected to the HDD's root mount point, fix whatever's gone wrong.  It's very distro-specific, and arguably OT for SF, but that's the route I'd take if it were my machine.

Comment: How old is this system? Which version of filesystem/glibc did you just upgrade from?

Comment: Using the `--force` option was particularly ill-advised. If you were attempting the [move to /usr/bin](https://www.archlinux.org/news/binaries-move-to-usrbin-requiring-update-intervention/), you have obviosly b0rked it and would be better off reinstalling.

Answer (score 1):

Never use the `--force` option, and here you must [upgrade glibc and filesystem together,](https://www.archlinux.org/news/update-filesystem-201301-1-and-glibc-217-2-together/) otherwise `/lib` is fully erased.

I'm not quiet sure about this, but if you have an archlinux boot media,

1. Install `glibc` and `filesystem` with pacstrap or something again
2. Fix the /lib link (perhaps link /usr/lib to it, I don't remember the details)